# "Боюсь больше пить"

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Услышал сегодня фразу "Я боюсь больше пить" в том смысле, что собеседник боялся проблем с понятно чем.

На мой взгляд, можно сказать "не могу / не хочу больше пить" или "боюсь ещё пить", хотя последнее тоже вроде бы не совсем гладко звучит.

А вы как считаете?

Comment: Можно подставить другой глагол, тогда яснее становится картина: разве скажешь "я боюсь больше летать/спать/лечиться"? Лучше изменить на "я боюсь теперь/уже пить" или на "я больше не буду пить". Всегда в таких случаях помогает замена слова на какое-нибудь другое по смыслу - чётче проясняется нелепость фразы.

Answer (score 3):

В контексте застолья это может звучать складно. 
Мол: 
-Будешь ещё?
-Нет, я боюсь больше пить (больше, чем уже выпил) 
Здесь имеется прямое количественное сравнение, и на мой взгляд, всё звучит вполне здраво.
Есть ещё схожие варианты где боюсь звучит хорошо: "Я могу больше пить, но я боюсь больше пить" "Я не хочу больше пить, да я и боюсь больше пить".

Идеально звучит: "Я боюсь продолжать/продолжить пить." и "Я боюсь запить" Они чётко отражают мысль человека и, в отличие от приведённой в вопросе, не вызывают никакого дискомфорта.